# HSB -> HSL Converter

Tags: image-processing, color, image

Starting from an image I would like to apply a custom filter to an image.

I have thought and implemented this filter in HSL space and it goes like this :

- Boost the saturation of the pixels that have a S value > .5
- Decrease the ones where S < .5.

Would I have the HSL Values instead of the HSB the code would go like this :

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
ImageColorSpace[img]
img = ImageResize[img, 128];
img = ColorConvert[img, "HSB"];
imgd = ImageData[img];
newimg = ({#[[1]], 1/(1 + E^(10*#[[2]]*(#[[2]] - .5))), #[[3]]} & /@ 
  imgd[[#]]) & /@ Range[Length[imgd]];
newimg = Image[newimg]
```

**My Problem :** I cannot figure out how to convert HSB (only hue based space in M9 to my knowledge) to HSL.

Comment: http://ariya.blogspot.com.ar/2008/07/converting-between-hsl-and-hsv.html

Comment: @belisarius, Thank You, I don`t quite get this syntax. Especially the role of the '*'. Could you tell me how to read that symbol there ?

Comment: *var is a pointer to var, just ignore it

Comment: [It's got to do with pointers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnXkiAKbUPg)

Comment: Using the formulas in [wiki's "HSL and HSV" page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), I think a formula from one to the other can be derived.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [the formulas in Wikipedia's "HSL and HSV" page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Formal_derivation), a function from HSB -> RGB can be defined as (where $h,s,b\in[0,1]$):

```
Clear[HSBtoRGB]
HSBtoRGB[{h_, s_, b_}] := Module[{c, x, R1, G1, B1},
  c = b s;
  x = c (1 - Abs[Mod[6 h, 2] - 1]);
  b - c + Piecewise[{
     {{c, x, 0}, 0 <= h < 1/6},
     {{x, c, 0}, 1/6 <= h < 2/6},
     {{0, c, x}, 2/6 <= h < 3/6},
     {{0, x, c}, 3/6 <= h < 4/6},
     {{x, 0, c}, 4/6 <= h < 5/6},
     {{c, 0, x}, 5/6 <= h < 1}
     }, {0, 0, 0}]
  ]
```

Also function from RGB -> HSL (where $r,g,b\in[0,1]$):

```
Clear[RGBtoHSL]
RGBtoHSL[{r_, g_, b_}] := Module[{m, M, c, h, s, l},
  {m, M} = Through[{Min, Max}[r, g, b]];
  c = M - m;
  h = 1/6 Piecewise[{{0, c == 0},
      {Mod[(g - b)/c, 6], M == r},
      {(b - r)/c + 2, M == g},
      {(r - g)/c + 4, M == b}}];
  l = (m + M)/2;
  s = Piecewise[{{c/(1 - Abs[2 l - 1]), c != 0}}, 0];
  {h, s, l}
  ]
```

So by using `RGBtoHSL[HSBtoRGB[ hsb ]]`, a HSB color can be converted to HSL one.

This composite function evaluates to results generally the same as that does in Sjoerd C. de Vries'es answer, only differs on some boundary values:

```
Function[hsb, Grid[{{
       Graphics[{Hue @@ hsb, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 50],
       {
         {hsb, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
         RGBtoHSL[HSBtoRGB[hsb]],
         HSVtoHSL @@ hsb
         } //
        Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
       }}, Frame -> True]] /@
   Join[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3],
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {18, 3}]] //
  Row[Riffle[#, "   "]] & // Quiet
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A quick conversion from [the page belisarius linked to](http://ariya.blogspot.com.ar/2008/07/converting-between-hsl-and-hsv.html):

```
HSVtoHSL[h_, s_, v_] :=
 Module[{ss, ll},
  ll = (2 - s) v;
  ss = s v;
  ss /= If[ll <= 1, ll, 2 - ll];
  ll /= 2;
  {h, ss, ll}
]


HSLtoHSV[hh_, ss_, ll_] :=
 Module[{s = ss, l = ll},
  l *= 2;
  s *= If[(l <= 1), l, 2 - l];
  {hh, (2*s)/(l + s), (l + s)/2}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks god the code wasn't done is golfscript