# Okhsl colour space

Tags: function-construction, color

I am trying to recreate the Okhsl colour space from [here](https://bottosson.github.io/posts/colorpicker/). Below are the hue-saturation plots desired:

[image]

[image]

I can create something similar (code adapted from [here](https://observablehq.com/@shan/oklab-color-wheel)) with

```
HSLtoHSV[hh_, ss_, ll_] := Module[{s = ss, l = ll}, l *= 2;
   s *= If[(l <= 1), l, 2 - l];
   {hh, (2*s)/(l + s), (l + s)/2}];
gamma[x_] := If[x >= 0.0031308, 1.055*x^(1/2.4) - 0.055, 12.92*x];
oklab[L_, a_, b_] := 
  Module[{l, m, s}, l = L + 0.3963377774*a + 0.2158037573*b; 
   m = L - 0.1055613458*a - 0.0638541728*b; 
   s = L - 0.0894841775*a - 1.2914855480*b;
   RGBColor[gamma[+4.0767245293*l - 3.3072168827*m + 0.2307590544*s], 
    gamma[-1.2681437731*l + 2.6093323231*m - 0.3411344290*s], 
    gamma[-0.0041119885*l - 0.7034763098*m + 1.7068625689*s]]];
oklch[l_, c_, h_] := 
  oklab[l^(3/2(*1*)), c l Cos[2 Pi h], c l  Sin[2 Pi h]];
oklchs[l_, c_, h_] := Lighter[oklch[l, c, h], l^3];
lchs[l_, c_, h_] := Lighter[LCHColor[l, c, h], l^3];
GraphicsGrid[{{ArrayPlot[
    Reverse@Table[oklchs[l, 1, h], {l, 0, 1, .01}, {h, 0, 1, .01}], 
    ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> False], 
   ArrayPlot[
    Reverse@Table[lchs[l, 1, h], {l, 0, 1, .01}, {h, 0, 1, .01}], 
    ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> False], 
   ArrayPlot[
    Reverse@Thread@
      Table[Hue[##] & @@ Quiet@HSLtoHSV[h, 1, l], {h, 0, 1, .01}, {l, 
        0, 1, .01}], ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> False]}}]
ColorConvert[%, "Grayscale"]
```

[image]

[image]

but I would really appreciate help adapting the C++ to the Wolfram language, as I have tried but failed to translate (since I can't seem to decode the C++).

Helpful hints also most welcome!

Comment: At the bottom of the page, there is a source code in C++ (namely the function `srgb_to_okhsl`). Even if you don't know C++, I think it is quite verbose for translating into Mathematica. Have you tried that?

Comment: @martin commentary about different reference points in the color space used by mathematica, found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101627/63039) might be useful for you.

Comment: @martin: Where did you get the inner code of your `HSLtoHSV` from?

Comment: @azerbajdzan from here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17850/9923

Comment: I thought it was somewhere from the C code. Can you produce the image of `sRGB` color space? Because then there is a function `srgb_to_okhsl` in the C code which would convert it to your desired color space.

Comment: @azerbajdzan just an adaptation (or helpful hints) of c++ to mma would be appreciated

Comment: You have to rewrite the whole c++ code to mma and since it is quite long it would also be quite time consuming. Maybe if you can ask the authors of the code whether they have (or could produce) icc color profile file (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) which mathematica can deal with by `ColorProfileData`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I'm only interested in rgb to hsl really

Comment: Yes, but the function `srgb_to_okhsl` is dependent on about 80% of the c++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments http://bottosson.github.io/misc/ok_color.h contains all relevant functions in C, which use only basic mathematical functions of C. Phrasing the code to Mathematica is thus rather simple but tedious since its quite a bit of code. Since I am bored and 500 rep are 500 rep here we go:

```
(** https://bottosson.github.io/posts/gamutclipping/#oklab-to-linear-srgb-conversion **)
Lab[l_,a_,b_]:=Lab[<|"L"->l,"a"->a,"b"->b|>]
Lab[asoc_Association][s_String]:=asoc[s]

RGB[r_,g_,b_]:=RGB[<|"r"->r,"g"->g,"b"->b|>]
RGB[asoc_Association][s_String]:=asoc[s]
RGB/:ToColor[RGB[asoc_Association]]:=RGBColor[asoc["r"],asoc["g"],asoc["b"]]

linearsRGBtoOKLAB[c_RGB]:=Module[{l,m,s},
    l=0.4122214708 * c["r"] + 0.5363325363 * c["g"] + 0.0514459929 * c["b"];
    m=0.2119034982  * c["r"] + 0.6806995451  * c["g"] + 0.1073969566 * c["b"];
    s=0.0883024619 * c["r"] + 0.2817188376 * c["g"] + 0.6299787005 * c["b"];
    
    l=l^(1/3);
    m=m^(1/3);
    s=s^(1/3);
    Lab[
        0.2104542553 * l + 0.7936177850 * m - 0.0040720468 * s,
        1.9779984951 * l - 2.4285922050 * m + 0.4505937099 * s,
        0.0259040371 * l + 0.7827717662 * m - 0.8086757660 * s
    ]
]

OKLABtolinearsRGB[c_Lab]:=Module[{l,m,s},
    l = c["L"] + 0.3963377774 * c["a"] + 0.2158037573 * c["b"];
    m = c["L"] - 0.1055613458 * c["a"] - 0.0638541728 * c["b"];
    s = c["L"] - 0.0894841775 * c["a"] - 1.2914855480 * c["b"];
    
    l=l^3;
    m=m^3;
    s=s^3;
    
    RGB[
         +4.0767416621 * l - 3.3077115913 * m + 0.2309699292 * s,
        -1.2684380046 * l + 2.6097574011 * m - 0.3413193965 * s,
        -0.0041960863 * l - 0.7034186147 * m + 1.7076147010 * s
    ]
]

(** https://bottosson.github.io/posts/gamutclipping/#intersection-with-srgb-gamut **)

(*Finds the maximum saturation possible for a given hue that fits in sRGB
Saturation here is defined as S = C/L
a and b must be normalized so a^2 + b^2 == 1*)
computeMaxSaturation[a_,b_]:=Module[{k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, wl, wm, ws},
    If[-1.88170328 * a - 0.80936493 * b > 1,
        (* Red component *)
        k0 = +1.19086277; k1 = +1.76576728; k2 = +0.59662641; k3 = +0.75515197; k4 = +0.56771245;
        wl = +4.0767416621; wm = -3.3077115913; ws = +0.2309699292;,
    (*else*) If[1.81444104 * a - 1.19445276 * b > 1,
        (* Green component *)
        k0 = +0.73956515; k1 = -0.45954404; k2 = +0.08285427; k3 = +0.12541070; k4 = +0.14503204;
        wl = -1.2684380046; wm = +2.6097574011; ws = -0.3413193965;,
    (*else*) 
        (* Blue component *)
        k0 = +1.35733652; k1 = -0.00915799; k2 = -1.15130210; k3 = -0.50559606; k4 = +0.00692167;
        wl = -0.0041960863; wm = -0.7034186147; ws = +1.7076147010;
    ]];
    
    Block[{S,kl,km,ks,l,m,s,ldS,mdS,sdS,ldS2,mdS2,sdS2,f,f1,f2},
        (*Approximate max saturation using a polynomial:*)
        S = k0 + k1 * a + k2 * b + k3 * a * a + k4 * a * b;
        (*Do one step Halley's method to get closer
        this gives an error less than 10e6, except for some blue hues where the dS/dh is close to infinite
        this should be sufficient for most applications, otherwise do two/three steps*) 
        kl = +0.3963377774 * a + 0.2158037573 * b;
        km = -0.1055613458 * a - 0.0638541728 * b;
        ks = -0.0894841775 * a - 1.2914855480 * b;
        
        l=(1. + S * kl);
        m=(1. + S * km);
        s=(1. + S * ks);
        
        ldS = 3. * kl * l * l;
        mdS = 3. * km * m * m;
        sdS = 3. * ks * s * s;
        
        ldS2 = 6. * kl * kl * l;
        mdS2 = 6. * km * km * m;
        sdS2 = 6. * ks * ks * s;

        l=l^3;
        m=m^3;
        s=s^3;
        
        f  = wl * l     + wm * m     + ws * s;
        f1 = wl * ldS  + wm * mdS  + ws * sdS;
        f2 = wl * ldS2 + wm * mdS2 + ws * sdS2;
        S = S - f * f1 / (f1*f1 - 0.5 * f * f2);
        
        Return[S]
    ]   
]

LC[l_,c_]:=LC[<|"L"->l,"C"->c|>]
LC[asoc_Association][s_String]:=asoc[s]
(*finds L_cusp and C_cusp for a given hue
a and b must be normalized so a^2 + b^2 == 1*)
findCusp[a_,b_]:=Module[{Scusp,RGBatMax,Lcusp,Ccusp},
    (*First, find the maximum saturation (saturation S = C/L)*)
    Scusp=computeMaxSaturation[a,b];
    (*Convert to linear sRGB to find the first point where at least one of r,g or b >= 1:*)
    RGBatMax=OKLABtolinearsRGB[Lab[1,Scusp*a,Scusp*b]];
    Lcusp=(1./Max[RGBatMax["r"],RGBatMax["g"],RGBatMax["b"]])^(1/3);
    Ccusp=Lcusp*Scusp;
    LC[Lcusp,Ccusp]
]

(* Finds intersection of the line defined by 
L = L0 * (1 - t) + t * L1;
C = t * C1;
a and b must be normalized so a^2 + b^2 == 1*)
findGamutIntersection[a_,b_,L1_,C1_,L0_,LCcusp_LC]:=Module[{t},
    (*Find the intersection for upper and lower half seprately*)
    If[(((L1 - L0) * LCcusp["C"] - (LCcusp["L"] - L0) * C1) <= 0.),
        (*Lower half*)
        t= LCcusp["C"] * L0 / (C1 *  LCcusp["L"] +  LCcusp["C"] * (L0 - L1));,
    (*else*)
        (*Upper half*)
        (*First intersect with triangle*)
        t = LCcusp["C"] * (L0 - 1.) / (C1 * (LCcusp["L"] - 1.) + LCcusp["C"] * (L0 - L1));
        
        (*Then one step Halley's method*)
        Block[{dL,dC,kl,km,ks,ldt,mdt,sdt},
            dL = L1 - L0;
            dC = C1;

            kl = +0.3963377774 * a + 0.2158037573 * b;
            km = -0.1055613458 * a - 0.0638541728 * b;
            ks = -0.0894841775 * a - 1.2914855480 * b;

            ldt = dL + dC * kl;
            mdt = dL + dC * km;
            sdt = dL + dC * ks;
            (* If higher accuracy is required, 2 or 3 iterations of the following block can be used:*)
            Block[{LCl,LCc,l,m,s,ldt1,mdt1,sdt1,ldt2,mdt2,sdt2,r,r1,r2,ur,tr,g,g1,g2,ug,tg,b0,b1,b2,ub,tb},
                LCl = L0 * (1. - t) + t * L1;
                LCc = t * C1;

                l = LCl + LCc * kl;
                m = LCl + LCc * km;
                s = LCl + LCc * ks;

                ldt1 = 3 * ldt * l * l;
                mdt1 = 3 * mdt * m * m;
                sdt1 = 3 * sdt * s * s;

                ldt2 = 6 * ldt * ldt * l;
                mdt2 = 6 * mdt * mdt * m;
                sdt2 = 6 * sdt * sdt * s;
                
                l=l^3;
                m=m^3;
                s=s^3;
                
                r = 4.0767416621 * l - 3.3077115913 * m + 0.2309699292 * s - 1;
                r1 = 4.0767416621 * ldt1 - 3.3077115913 * mdt1 + 0.2309699292 * sdt1;
                r2 = 4.0767416621 * ldt2 - 3.3077115913 * mdt2 + 0.2309699292 * sdt2;

                ur = r1 / (r1 * r1 - 0.5 * r * r2);
                tr = -r * ur;

                g = -1.2684380046 * l + 2.6097574011 * m - 0.3413193965 * s - 1;
                g1 = -1.2684380046 * ldt1 + 2.6097574011 * mdt1 - 0.3413193965 * sdt1;
                g2 = -1.2684380046 * ldt2 + 2.6097574011 * mdt2 - 0.3413193965 * sdt2;

                ug = g1 / (g1 * g1 - 0.5 * g * g2);
                tg = -g * ug;

                b0 = -0.0041960863 * l - 0.7034186147 * m + 1.7076147010 * s - 1;
                b1 = -0.0041960863 * ldt1 - 0.7034186147 * mdt1 + 1.7076147010 * sdt1;
                b2 = -0.0041960863 * ldt2 - 0.7034186147 * mdt2 + 1.7076147010 * sdt2;

                ub = b1 / (b1 * b1 - 0.5 * b0 * b2);
                tb = -b0 * ub;

                tr = If[ur >= 0, tr , 3.402823*10^38];
                tg = If[ug >= 0, tg , 3.402823*10^38];
                tb = If[ub >= 0, tb , 3.402823*10^38];
                t += Min[tr,tg, tb];                            
            ];
        ];  
    ];
    Return[t]
]
findGamutIntersection[a_,b_,L1_,C1_,L0_]:=Module[{LCcusp},
    (*Find the cusp of the gamut triangle*)
    LCcusp=findCusp[a,b];
    findGamutIntersection[a,b,L1,C1,L0,LCcusp]
]

HSL[h_,s_,l_]:=HSL[<|"h"->h,"s"->s,"l"->l|>]
HSL[asoc_Association][s_String]:=asoc[s]

ST[s_,t_]:=ST[<|"S"->s,"T"->t|>]
ST[asoc_Association][s_String]:=asoc[s]

toe[x_]:=With[{k1=0.206,k2=0.03},With[{k3=(1.+k1)/(1.+k2)},
    0.5 * (k3 * x - k1 + Sqrt[(k3 * x - k1) * (k3 * x - k1) + 4 * k2 * k3 * x])
]]

toeInv[x_]:=With[{k1=0.206,k2=0.03},With[{k3=(1.+k1)/(1.+k2)},
    (x * x + k1 * x) / (k3 * (x + k2))
]]

toST[cusp_LC]:=With[{l=cusp["L"],c=cusp["C"]},ST[c/l,c/(1.-l)]]
getSTmid[a_,b_]:=With[{
    s=0.11516993 + 1. / (
        +7.44778970 + 4.15901240 * b
        + a * (-2.19557347 + 1.75198401 * b
            + a * (-2.13704948 - 10.02301043 * b
                + a * (-4.24894561 + 5.38770819 * b + 4.69891013 * a
                    )))
        ),t=0.11239642 + 1. / (
        +1.61320320 - 0.68124379 * b
        + a * (+0.40370612 + 0.90148123 * b
            + a * (-0.27087943 + 0.61223990 * b
                + a * (+0.00299215 - 0.45399568 * b - 0.14661872 * a
                    )))
        )},
    ST[s,t]
]

CS[c0_,cMid_,cMax_]:=CS[<|"c0"->c0,"cMid"->cMid,"cMax"->cMax|>]
CS[asoc_Association][s_String]:=asoc[s]
getCS[l_,a_,b_]:=Module[{LCcusp,STmax,k,c0,cMid,cMax},
    LCcusp=findCusp[a,b];
    cMax=findGamutIntersection[a,b,l,1.,l,LCcusp];
    STmax=toST[LCcusp];
    
    (*Scale factor to compensate for the curved part of gamut shape:*)
    k= cMax / Min[(l * STmax["S"]), (1 - l) * STmax["T"]];
    
    Block[{STmid,ca,cb},
        STmid=getSTmid[a,b];
        ca=l*STmid["S"];
        cb=(1-l)*STmid["T"];
        (*Use a soft minimum function, instead of a sharp triangle shape to get a smooth value for chroma.*)
        cMid=0.9 * k * Sqrt[Sqrt[1. / (1. / ca^4 + 1. / cb^4)]];
    ];
    
    Block[{ca,cb},
        (*for C_0, the shape is independent of hue, so ST are constant. Values picked to roughly be the average values of ST.*)
        ca = l * 0.4;
        cb = (1. - l) * 0.8;

        (*Use a soft minimum function, instead of a sharp triangle shape to get a smooth value for chroma.*)
        c0 = Sqrt[1. / (1. / ca^2 + 1. / cb^2)];
    ];
    Return[CS[c0,cMid,cMax]]
]

sRGBtransferFunction[a_]:=If[0.0031308>=a,12.92*a,1.055*(a^.4166666666666667)-0.055]
sRGBtransferFunctionInverse[a_]:=If[0.04045<a,((a+0.055)/1.055)^2.4,a/12.92]

OkhsltosRGB[hsl_HSL]:=Module[{h,s,l,a,b,cs,c0,cMid,cMax},
    h=hsl["h"];
    s=hsl["s"];
    l=hsl["l"];
    
    If[l == 1.0,
        Return[RGB[1., 1., 1.]];
    ];
    If[l == 0., 
        Return[RGB[0., 0., 0.]];
    ];
    
    a = Cos[2.* Pi * h];
    b = Sin[2.* Pi * h];
    l = toeInv[l];
    
    cs = getCS[l, a, b];
    c0 = cs["c0"];
    cMid = cs["cMid"];
    cMax = cs["cMax"];
    Block[{mid,midInv,c,t,k0,k1,k2,rgb},
        mid = 0.8;
        midInv = 1.25;
        If[s<mid,
            t = midInv * s;

            k1 = mid * c0;
            k2 = (1. - k1 / cMid);

            c = t * k1 / (1. - k2 * t);,
        (*else*)
            t = (s - mid)/ (1 - mid);

            k0 = cMid;
            k1 = (1. - mid) * cMid * cMid * midInv * midInv / c0;
            k2 = (1. - (k1) / (cMax - cMid));

            c = k0 + t * k1 / (1. - k2 * t);
        ];
        rgb=OKLABtolinearsRGB[Lab[l,c*a,c*b]];
        Return[RGB[
            sRGBtransferFunction[rgb["r"]],
            sRGBtransferFunction[rgb["g"]],
            sRGBtransferFunction[rgb["b"]]
        ]];
    ];
]

ArcTan2[y_,x_]:=Piecewise[{{ArcTan[y/x],x>0},{ArcTan[y/x]+Pi,x<0&&y>=0},{ArcTan[y/x]-Pi,x<0&&y<0},{Pi/2,x<$MachineEpsilon&&y>0},{-Pi/2,x<$MachineEpsilon&&y<0},{Undefined,True}}]
sRGBtoOkhsl[rgb_RGB]:=Module[{lab,c,a,b,l,h,cs,c0,cMid,cMax},
    lab=linearsRGBtoOKLAB[RGB[
            sRGBtransferFunctionInverse[rgb["r"]],
            sRGBtransferFunctionInverse[rgb["g"]],
            sRGBtransferFunctionInverse[rgb["b"]]
    ]];
    c = Sqrt[lab["a"] * lab["a"] + lab["b"] * lab["b"]];
    a = lab["a"]/ c;
    b = lab["b"]/ c;
    
    l=lab["L"];
    h = 0.5 + 0.5 * ArcTan2[-lab["b"], -lab["a"]] / Pi;

    cs = getCS[l, a, b];
    c0 = cs["c0"];
    cMid = cs["cMid"];
    cMax = cs["cMax"];
    
    (*Inverse of the interpolation in okhsl_to_srgb:*)
    Block[{mid,midInv,t,s,k0,k1,k2,hsl},
        mid = 0.8;
        midInv = 1.25;
        If[c < cMid,
            k1 = mid * c0;
            k2 = (1. - k1 / cMid);

            t = c / (k1 + k2 * c);
            s = t * mid;,
        (*else*)
            k0 = cMid;
            k1 = (1. - mid) * cMid * cMid * midInv * midInv / c0;
            k2 = (1. - (k1) / (cMax - cMid));

            t = (c - k0) / (k1 + k2 * (c - k0));
            s = mid + (1. - mid) * t;
        ];

        Return[HSL[h,s,toe[l]]];
    ];
]
```

where the main conversion methods are `OkhsltosRGB` and `sRGBtoOkhsl`. I adapted the C code quite literally so there are a few places where one could optimize it using some features of Wolfram Language. But coming to the point

```
Table[OkhsltosRGB[HSL[h, 0.5, l]] // ToColor, {l, 0, 1, 0.005}, {h, 0,
      1, 0.005}] // Reverse // ArrayPlot;
Table[OkhsltosRGB[HSL[h, 1, l]] // ToColor, {l, 0, 1, 0.005}, {h, 0, 
     1, 0.005}] // Reverse // ArrayPlot;
Grid[{{%%, %}}]
```

> [image: Okhsl]

which looks like the *Okhsl* color space [referenced](https://bottosson.github.io/posts/colorpicker/). Since it is quite a bit of code which I adapted mostly by hand with the help of copy&replace I can not be sure that it is working correctly in all cases. Some of the `Min` and `Max` functions might need additional code to handle non-numerical values like their C equivalents but I am not sure if those can actually happen in normal use since I have absolutely no clue whatsoever what this code actually does. If someone finds any bugs or errors please let me know and I will try to look into it.

Comment: You really must have been bored :-) I wonder what is so special about this color space, since there seems to be a mistake already in the original code because of the inconsistency caused by the blue line in image. Or was it an intension to have such an inconsistency? ... I know the questions are more appropriate for OP or author of the code.

Comment: @N0va thank you! Seems to fo the trick.. Will take a closer look in a bit

Comment: @azerbajdzan The fact that Okhsl varies smoothly but not evenly seems to be inherited from HSL. The overall goal seemed to be improving hue, saturation and lightness of HSL to be closer to the ones perceived by the human eye using something called Oklab.

Comment: But you see the fat blue line... which is only in one place but other transitions of tints are smooth. So I guess this might be some mistake already in the original code.